# What is the proper way to have only one header with Open Drawer and Back button?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

What I need is a single header with a `back` button on `StackScreen2` and a toggle drawer button in `StackScreen1`.

I apologise for my poor writing and English.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function StackScreen1({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>StackScreen1</Text>
            <Button title="Go To StackScreen2" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("StackScreen2")} />
        </View>
    )
}

function StackScreen2() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>StackScreen2</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

function DrawerScreen1() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="StackScreen1" component={StackScreen1} />
            <Stack.Screen name="StackScreen2" component={StackScreen2} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}

function DrawerScreen2() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>DrawerScreen2</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function Test3() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator>
                <Drawer.Screen name="DrawerScreen1" component={DrawerScreen1} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="DrawerScreen2" component={DrawerScreen2} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

[StackScreen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgz0T.png)
[StackScreen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qt78.png)

I tried hiding drawer header but then I don't have toggle drawer button anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code for drawer navigation:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator useLegacyImplementation initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

You can check more about drawer [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/).

Comment: No. I have read that document. It doesn't mention anything about stack being inside drawer.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you!

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Ionicons, FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Button, View, Text, Pressable,Image } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';


function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SettingsScreen')}
      />


    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      useLegacyImplementation
      //  screenOptions={{
      //     drawerLabelStyle: { fontSize: 17, color: '#000',marginLeft:-30 }
      //   }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={DetailsScreen}
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}


function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="SettingsScreen"
        component={MyDrawer}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons name="md-home" size={24} color={'#eee'} />
          ),
          tabBarStyle: { position: 'absolute' },
          tabBarActiveTintColor: '#eee',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#eee',
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="DetailsScreen"
        component={DetailsScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Image source={{uri:"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTUAN0zLcvLFjdaYN1dBRSKoIuJndRW6VuX85w2yzEzxvTwO3B0Y_gv1x8kVDISNKJEbq0&usqp=CAU"}}
            style={{width:24,height:24,borderRadius:24}} />
          ),
          tabBarStyle: { position: 'absolute' },
          tabBarActiveTintColor: '#eee',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#eee',
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>2</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeScreen">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="HomeScreen"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          name="SettingsScreen"
          component={MyTabs}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```